# Error building from the Windows Command Prompt via vcbuild

Tags: windows, command, prompt, vcbuild

I am trying to execute vcbuild via the command prompt. Just using

```
vcbuild project.vcproj
```

doesn't work and I've tried using the whole path :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe project.vcproj
```

That give the error : 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, ...

so I tried it with '

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe' project.vcproj
```

That give the error "The system cannot find the path specified"

- The path does exists

Thanks any help would be much appreciated.

NOTE : this is to be executed by TeamCity (CI Server)
++ for some reason using "" doesn't work, on input in TeamCity's command execution responds with : "Invalid command executable specified"

Comment: Use the Visual Studio Command Prompt from the Start menu.

Comment: I am doing it in a CI Server, TeamCity

Comment: @Joey's comment about quoting is correct, but I would adjust your `PATH` environment variable to include the Visual Studio path rather than deal with locating the binary in your command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes instead:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe" project.vcproj
```

Quoting in `cmd` is only possible with double quotes, regardless of what you may or may not be used to from Unix shells.

Comment: I am doing it in TeamCity and it response with the error on input : "Invalid command executable specified" Do you know any other way?

Comment: If you have to give the path to an executable and its arguments in separate fields, then you should probably leave out the quotes again.

Comment: I ended up going to system settings and adding it as a environment variable.